# How to create a new array using the data from the old one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I wonder, is it possible to create from the given json data, for example:

```
data0 = [ {id: name1, value1: 5, value2: 13}, {id: name2, value1: 2, value2: 5}, {id: name3, value1: 4, value2: 6}, {id: name4, value1: 3, value2: 7} ];
```

The following array, with two more objects, for example:

```
var data = [ {id: sum1, value: 14}, {id: name1_, value: 8}, {id: name2_, value: 3 }, {id: name3_, value: 2}, {id: name4_, value: 4} {id: sum2, value: 31];
```

The first and the last objecs have the value equal a sum of all value1 and value2 respectfully. And all other objects have a value = difference between value2 and value1.

The data0 can have different values for object properties, depending on the kind of report.

I need it for my d3 waterfall chart I'm using in Microstrategy. Thus, I don't have to change the js code a lot, but just to add a code to create a new array and visualization will be built using data from it.

The initial data0 I have in csv format:

```
id,value1,value2
name1,5,13
name2,2,5
name3,4,6
name4,3,7
```

As I understand, the function d3.csv reads the data in csv formate like a json data, taking the title (first row) as the properties of the 4 objects (in this case), where every following row containes the values of the properties for each object.

I call the dataset function using the following code:

```
d3.csv("data0.csv", function(error, data) {
var values = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {return key !== "id";});

data.forEach(function(d) {
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
d.value = +d[values[i]];
return d;
}});
```

How I suppose to refer to all value1 and value2 taking into account that the property name can be different as well (not "value1" and "value2"), and find each sum. Shall I use for loop with i and j?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It's certainly possible and can be achieved in many different ways. Is it allowed to mutate (change) the original array or does it have to be a copy?

Comment: better ask a new question, because the restructuring has nothing to do with the csv data. also, please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Can you please supply the csv(s) you are reading?

Comment: @TobyFlemming, I've just added to the question, how csv file i'm reading looks like. However, it can have any other property name, depends on the report generated later in Microstrategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can take [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this task.

```js
var data0 = [{ id: 'name1', value1: 5, value2: 13 }, { id: 'name2', value1: 2, value2: 5 }, { id: 'name3', value1: 4, value2: 6 }, { id: 'name4', value1: 3, value2: 7 }],
    result = function (array) {
        var sum1 = 0,
            sum2 = 0,
            r = array.map(function (a) {
                sum1 += a.value1;
                sum2 += a.value2;
                return { id: '_' + a.id, value: a.value2 - a.value1 };
            });
        return [{ id: 'sum1', value: sum1 }].concat(r, { id: 'sum2', value: sum2 });
    }(data0);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Nina! :)
I've edited the question a bit, maybe you have any idea how to create new array in that case?

Comment: better ask a new question, because the restructuring has nothing to do with the csv data. also, please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't sure what your id's were to be as it looked like you were using variables.  I converted them into strings in this case.  Enjoy!

Code could have been compact but i thought this would make it more readable for you in future.  Feel free to ask any further questions, happy to help!

```js
var data = [ 
  {
    id: 'name1', 
    value1: 5, 
    value2: 13
  }, 
  {
    id: 'name2', 
    value1: 2, 
    value2: 5
  }, 
  {
   id: 'name3', 
   value1: 4, 
   value2: 6
  }, 
  {
    id: 'name4', 
    value1: 3, 
    value2: 7
  } 
];

// Calculate sums
var value1Sum = 0;
var value2Sum = 0;

data.forEach(function(object) {
  value1Sum += object.value1;
  value2Sum += object.value2;
});

// Insert sums at front and back
data.unshift({
  id: 'sum1',
  value: value1Sum
});

data.push({
  id: 'sum2',
  value: value2Sum
});

// Calculate differences
data = data.map(function(object, idx) {
  if (idx === 0 || idx === data.length - 1) {
    return object;
  }
  
  return {
    id: object.id + '_',
    value: object.value2 - object.value1
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)
I've edited the question a bit, could you please take a look?

Comment: Having a look now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
data0 = [ {id: name1, value1: 5, value2: 13}, {id: name2, value1: 2, value2: 5}, {id: name3, value1: 4, value2: 6}, {id: name4, value1: 3, value2: 7} ];
var data = [];
var sum1 = 0;
var sum2 = 0; 
for (i = 0; i < data0.length; i++) {
  sum1 += data0[i].value1;
  sum2 += data0[i].value2;
  var diff = data0[i].value2 - data0[i].value1;
  data.push({id: 'name' + (i+1) + '_', value: diff});
}
data.unshift({id: 'sum1', value: sum1});
data.push({id: 'sum2', value: sum2});
```

Array.push() adds after the last Item of the Array, Array.unshift() before the first Item.

Comment: Thank you @Marius,
I've edited the question a bit, would appreciate if you could take a look.

Answer (score -1):

There are many different ways to achieve the result you need. One of them is to use `map` and `reduce` functions on the array items. You can read more about `map` and `reduce` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) .

```js
var  data0 = [ {id: 'name1', value1: 5, value2: 13}, {id: 'name2', value1: 2, value2: 5}, {id: 'name3', value1: 4, value2: 6}, {id: 'name4', value1: 3, value2: 7} ];

// calculate `sum1` and `sum2` as the sums of `value1` and `value2` respectively
var sums = data0.reduce(function (sums, item) {
    sums.sum1.value += item.value1;
    sums.sum2.value += item.value2;
    return sums;
}, {
    sum1: {id: 'sum1', value: 0},
    sum2: {id: 'sum2', value: 0}
});

// transform (map) the existing data and calculate `value` as a difference between `value2` and `value1`
var restOfData = data0.map(function (item) {
    return {
        id: item.id,
        value: item.value2 - item.value1
    };
});

// merge the obtained results into a single array
var data = [sums.sum1].concat(restOfData, [sums.sum2]);

document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

This code is even more readable if you're using ES2015 thanks to arrow functions and spread operator: http://codepen.io/mmiszy/pen/EKmmEy?editors=0010

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)
I've edited the question a bit, could you please take a look?

Comment: You should at least provide some explanation of what your code does.

Comment: @RostyslavaRomaniuk you should accept one of the answers and create a new question because you're describing a completely different issue now http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers